# Calculate distance to nearest neighbor in very large raster

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, raster

I have a large raster (145.927.240 cells) with categorical data. The data can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ESA_GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3

For each cell I would like to calculate the distance to the nearest neighbor of each class. What is the most efficient (i.e. feasible) way to do this? I've looked for suitable packages, but so far I haven't found one that does what I want (with a raster of that size).

To give some context:
I would like to combine several raster files, convert them to a data table to use them as input in different models and then convert the result back to a raster file.

Comment: Maybe some clues here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560919/r-finding-the-nearest-raster-cell-within-a-threshold-calculated-between-two-ras#comment29027020_19560919

Comment: R is not a very friendly tool for very large dataset. Especially that you want to run a nearest-neighbour analysis that unfortunately, you can not break your dataset into patches! Nonetheless,`spatstat` is a nice package for distance-based analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Turns out my question was kind of stupid, because apparently the distance function of the raster package does exactly what I want. Problem is, it's slow. Started the calculations nearly 19 hours ago and I still got not result. However, I found something that might help -> https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_speed_up_the_Euclidian_distance_estimation_in_a_raster_using_R

I'll post an answer here as soon as I've figured out how to speed this up significantly so that others have an answer too.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing mentioned here worked, but I found something else. Once I've got enough time I will post a function here that does the job. In the meantime, I found the solution there: https://www.gis-blog.com/nearest-neighbour-search-for-spatial-points-in-r/